# Question on the trace operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I understand why we must introduce it: If we have some PDE with Dirichlet boundary condition, $$ u|_{\partial\Omega} = g $$

no longer makes sense when $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ since the boundary is a null set. But how does introducing the trace operator actually mend this problem?

Comment: If $u$ was continuous up to the boundary, $u|_{\partial \Omega}$ would make sense as some continuous function. The trace theorem, informally, states that if $u \in W^{1,p}$, then $u|_{\partial \Omega}$ can still be defined as some $L^p(\partial \Omega)$ function. Since $u$ is not well-defined on null sets, one needs fancier notions, i.e. one writes $T(u)$ instead of $u|_{\partial \Omega}$, where $T(u)$ should equal $u|_{\partial\Omega}$ if, for instance, $u$ was continuous in the first place.

Comment: Ok, think this made it a bit more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that, for $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ for instance, $u\left|_{\partial \Omega} \right.$ cannot be uniquely defined since the boundary has measure $0$ (for $\Omega$ smooth enough at least).

However, it can be defined if $u$ is smooth enough : for instance, if $u$ is continuous, $u\left|_{\partial \Omega} \right.$ is already defined. The trace theorem states that there exists an unique linear and continuous operator (called the trace operator) that extends this trace from continuous functions to $H^1(\Omega)$, with values in $L^2(\partial \Omega)$.

EDIT : You have :

$$ T : C^0(\Omega) \cap H^1(\Omega) \subset H^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega) $$

which is the classical trace operator, well-defined as long as the function is continuous. (Actually, the image is in $C^0(\partial \Omega) \subset L^2(\partial \Omega)$ - at least when $\partial \Omega$ is compact, say.)

Now, you can show that $T$ can be extended uniquely to the whole $H^1(\Omega)$ in a way that preserves linearity and continuity. This means that you can actually give a meaning to the trace of a $H^1$ function - which wasn't obvious at the beginning.

This is particularly useful, as you mentioned it, for partial differential equation : this way, you don't need to ask your solution to be continuous. The space $H^1(\Omega)$ is very well-suited thanks to the trace for equations like $\Delta u = f$, $f$ being a data, and has the advantage of being a Hilbert space (while $C^0$ is not).

Comment: I still dont see how the trace operator "saves us" in this situation. If we have an  $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ that satisfies the weak form of our PDE, why does T: $ H^1(\Omega)$ 
 sending to $L^2(\partial \Omega)$ help us?

Comment: No, I mean that the trace operator has values in $L^2(\partial \Omega)$.

Comment: I am still not quite sure what I misunderstood, could you elaborate?

Comment: I will edit to explain it otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, understand it better now.